# Ajax jQuery call to ColdFusion component

Tags: jquery, coldfusion, cfc

I'm new to jQuery and am trying to create a login page that will do an Ajax call to a CFC that simply returns true or false on whether login was successfull.  My call is making it to the CFC with my arguments correctly, but what's getting returned is the problem.  If I set my datatype in jQuery to be "html", I see what looks like a copy of my entire page in html along with the "true" value I'm looking for.  But if I try setting it to "json" nothing happens.  I'm on ColdFusion 9, jQuery 1.6.2.

My jQuery function:

```
$(function() {  
    $('.error').hide();  
    $(".button").click(function() {  

        // validate form here  
        $('.error').hide();  
        var name = $("input#username").val();  
        var pass = $("input#password").val();  
        if (name == "") {  
            $("label#username_error").show();  
            $("input#username").focus();  
            return false;  
        }  
        else if (pass == "") {  
            $("label#password_error").show();  
            $("input#password").focus();  
            return false;  
        }  
        else {
            var bodyContent = $.ajax({
                  url: "cfc/Login.cfc?method=tryLogin&returnFormat=JSON",
                  global: false,
                  type: "POST",
                  data: {username:name,password:pass},
                  dataType: "json",
                  async:false,
                  success: function(msg){
                     alert(msg);
                  }
               }
            ).responseText;

        }
    }); 
});
```

My CFC code, VERY simple, I'm just trying to get this to return correctly for now:

```
<cfcomponent name="Login" output="false">
    <cffunction name="tryLogin" access="remote" output="false">
        <cfargument name="username" type="string" required="true"/>
        <cfargument name="password" type="string" required="true"/>
        <cfset var result = true />

        <cfreturn result />
    </cffunction>
</cfcomponent>
```

Comment: What do you mean when you say "nothing happens"?  Is the request made?  Can you see it in Firebug or any other HTTP watching util?  Is a response returned? Is it empty?

Comment: In the Application.cfc do you have this.secureJSON set to true or false? If true set it to false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say:

> If I set my datatype in jQuery to be "html", I see what looks like a copy of my entire page in html along with the "true" value I'm looking for.

Do you mean that you see your "true" value followed by ColdFusion debugging info?  If so, are you using Application.cfm or Application.cfc in your site?  If Application.cfc, this is a common problem with AJAX functionality.  You'll need to trap for an AJAX CFC request in your onRequestStart function, remove the OnRequest function for this request, and disable debugging.  Try adding this to your onRequestStart function:

```
<cfif LCase(Right(ARGUMENTS.TargetPage,3)) EQ "cfc">
<cfset StructDelete(THIS,"OnRequest")>
<cfsetting showdebugoutput="no">
</cfif>
```

Comment: I'm actually using a blank Application.cfm page for now, just to get things going.  I seem to get back the entire page, with the DOCTYPE tag at the top and lots of html until I see my "true" statement about half-way down.

Comment: Do you have debugging turned on in CF Admin?  Try turning it off and see if you just get the JSON data returned.

Comment: That did it!  Not sure why it was interfering like that, but it's coming through now!  Thanks!!

Comment: Debugging will insert a bunch of HTML content containing the various debugging content.  This will break any code that expects pure JSON to be returned.  Since you aren't using Application.cfc, I'm not sure how to selectively disable debugging for AJAX calls to CFCs.  As soon as you turn debugging back on in the CF Admin (assuming this is a development environment where debugging may be desired), AJAX CFC calls will break again.

Comment: Makes sense.  Thanks for the advice on setting up the Application.cfc guys, that's the direction I'll be moving as I get this going but wanted to keep things very simple and straight-forward while trying to figure this stuff out.  :)

Answer (score 2):

I thought CF9 changed that behaviour and that you no longer had to use the onRequestStart "hack" for Ajax-called CFCs.

I could of course be wrong  - but I thought that was the case...