# ColdFusion Application - using AJAX from the mm_wizard_login.cfm page. Not returning JSON

Tags: json, ajax, coldfusion

I am using ColdFusion 11. I inherited an application which uses the `mm_wizard_login` ColdFusion feature for their login functionality. Now I have to implement the change password functionality in this application.  So if the user logs in and the application finds that this user is logging in for the first time, it should redirect the user to change their initial password.

So I decided to use a jQuery third party modal plugin.

I have added the jQuery plugin functionality in the `mm_wizard_login.cfm` page. During the authentication process, the scenario where the user needs to change password, the `mm_wizard_authenticate.cfc` denies the login and redirects them back to the `mm_wizard_login.cfm` page and then the plugin opens up and allows user to type in their new password. After the user clicks the submit, in jQuery I am intercepting their submit and I am making an AJAX call to another cfc which is accepting the new password and calling a SQL Server stored procedure to change their password. This cfc method returns JSON back to the AJAX call but the returning value is not JSON, it is returning the HTML for the `mm_wizard_login.cfm` page itself.

Everything is working, except the AJAX call which is expecting JSON.

In Chrome dev tools, I went into the network tab and under response tab, It is returning back the HTML for `mm_wizard_login.cfm` page. I don't understand this.

Here is my AJAX call below:

```
var refData = $.ajax({ 
    url: 'testmethod.cfc', 
    method: 'POST',  
    dataType: 'json',
    data:{
        method:'ChangePassword', //Call the method                     
        jsonData: JSON.stringify($(formdata).serializeArray())
    }
})
.done (function (d) {
    if (d.Result == 'OK')
        $("#modal-custom").iziModal('#modal-custom','setTitle', d.message);
        $("#modal-custom").iziModal('#modal-custom','close');
    else{                                  
        changePwd_ErrorHandler(d.message);
    }
})
.fail (function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    changePwd_ErrorHandler(textStatus + '. Please try again');
});
```

After nothing worked then I just tried a basic AJAX call from my `mm_wizard_login.cfm` page, here it is below:

```
var test = $.ajax({
    url: 'testmethod.cfc',
    method: 'POST', 
    dataType: 'json',
    data:{
        method:'MethodTest', //Call the method
    }
})
.done (function (d) {

})
.fail (function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    alert('Unable to change password. Please try again');
});
```

This is not working either. It is returning the same thing. Not JSON but the HTML content of `mm_wizard_login.cfm`. Please help.

This is my test cfc function which is being called from the login page.

[Upate] My test cfc method:

```
<cffunction name="MethodTest" access="remote" output="true" returntype="string" returnformat="json"  hint="Adds/Edits User Info .">

    <cfset retJSON = '{"Result": "Error","message": "Action Failed", "TotalRecordCount":0}'>

    <cfreturn retJSON>
</cffunction>
```

Comment: Wow! In all my years of ColdFusion development I have never come across this `mm_wizard_login` "feature". Cheers for bringing it up. Anyway, looking at some articles about it I see nothing that suggests it returns JSON data. Why do you think it does? The `mm` prefix suggests that it was a Macromedia product. That probably dates back to before JSON was a thing. Perhaps it has been updated but I don't really know as I cannot find any source code. What we need to see is the `mm_wizard_login.cfm` code to see what it is doing with your request. It seems like you have the AJAX part working.

Comment: Actually after cleaning up your question I noticed that your AJAX is calling `testmethod.cfc`. That is the code we need to see to determine why it is not returning JSON.

Comment: MIguel, I inherited this application and after checking online i found out that dreamweaver provided a wizard for login functionality. So this mm_wizard login is by product of using dreamweaver to setup an application's login. And this login is just another cfm page which submits the credentials to a cfc page called "mm_wizard_authenticate.cfc" which goes to the database and validates the credentials. I wrote jquery ajax code in the mm_wizard_login.cfm page to go against another cfc function to do the "change password". The json should be returned by this cfc function but it's not.

Comment: I am using the the same change password cfc function which returns the json in my "change password" page if the user wants to change his/her password and it works without any issues.

Comment: miguel, i found this link online about the mm_wizard_login. [link](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/developing-applications/developing-cfml-applications/securing-applications/implementing-user-security.html)

Comment: Yes I found that link as well but it still does not show the code. Regardless, we need to see the code that you have written which is supposed to return JSON. Please include the details in your question.

Comment: ... and did you actually verify that CFC code works correctly before trying to use it from ajax? If not, do that first.

Comment: the cfc code IS working correctly from my "change password" page which allows the user to change their password. I had another thought. since the user is not logged in, is it possible that the cfc code is not accessible to the login page.

Comment: Guys, Even i tried using the coldfusion cfajaxproxy tag to do this. Same result, only html login page is returned not the json, here is the code: 

<cfajaxproxy cfc="extensions/components/common" jsclassname="testmethod"> 
var test = function(){ 
 // create an instance of the proxy. 
 var e = new testmethod(); 
 e.setHTTPMethod("POST");
 result = e.MethodTest(); 
 } 
 
test();

Comment: @ShanShimb3o In your current `MethodTest` you are returning a string representation of JSON data. When returnformat is JSON, CF will run your data through `serializeJSON` for you. Verify your not serializing twice.

Comment: @ShanShimb3o Based on what you have shared with us it seems the AJAX request is getting redirected to the login page. So seems your security is kicking in and blocking the AJAX call. It would make sense that you cannot change your password unless you are logged into the system or at least provide your current password as well.

Comment: Twillen, i am returning json same way in other webpages in this CF application. It works in those cases. So i would bet that the json is good.

Comment: Miguel, that's what i thought. I am noticing that if you are not logged in, any and all attempts to access any other page or cfc leads back to the login page. So i think same thing is happening with ajax. And i think mm_wizard_login functionality is automatically doing this and intercepting any requests.

Comment: All, I found the solution to this problem. Please see this link. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7323069/ajax-jquery-call-to-coldfusion-component?rq=1).  It seems that when using ajax to call a cfc function. you have to turn off debugging.  "Debugging will insert a bunch of HTML content containing the various debugging content. This will break any code that expects pure JSON to be returned. "